# generatedDensities Deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, vector-graphics

While generating png images from vector drawable for different configuration(lower API than 21)...
I'm using *AndroidStudio2.0 preview5* and *gradle:2.0.0-alpha5*...

In build.gradle-

> ```
> defaultConfig {
>    ...
>     //generate drawables from vectors
>     generatedDensities = ['hdpi','xxhdpi']
> }
> ```

**generatedDensities** is shown as **deprecated** by the IDE.

What is the new way to implement it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Seems like we should replace `generatedDensities` with `vectorDrawables.generatedDensities` at this point.

```
 defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.generatedDensities = ['hdpi','xxhdpi']
}
```

Comment: i figured it out...but it was showing error previously ..i guess the tools were not updated..